# ClassCastException: ArrayList cannot be cast to

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

This is the error that I am getting:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to MenuComponent
```

Here is the code that is causing me trouble:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
public class Menu extends MenuComponent{
  ArrayList menuComponents = new ArrayList();
  String name;
  String description;

  public Menu() {    
  }

  public Menu(String name, String description) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
  }

  public void add(MenuComponent menuComponent) {
    menuComponents.add(menuComponents);
  }

  public void remove(MenuComponent menuComponent) {
    menuComponents.remove(menuComponents);
  }

  public MenuComponent getChild(int i) {
    return (MenuComponent) menuComponents.get(i);
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  public void print() {
    System.out.println(getName());
    System.out.print("---" + getDescription());
    System.out.println("---");

    Iterator iterator = menuComponents.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {  
      MenuComponent menuComponent = (MenuComponent) iterator.next();
      menuComponent.print();
    }
  }

  public Iterator createIterator() {    
    return new CompositeIterator(menuComponents.iterator());
  }
}
```

The problem that is causing the error is in this line:

```
MenuComponent menuComponent = (MenuComponent) iterator.next();
```

I've tried messing with it, but am having no luck. Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: menuComponent is an ArrayList, so you cannot cast it to your class MenuComponents - the two methods called add & remove should have '(menuComponent)' instead of '(menuComponents)'

Answer (score 2):

That´s the disadvantage of using the raw type of the `ArrayList`, you don´t notice if you do a simple mistake. You should rather declare the `ArrayList` as `ArrayList<MenuComponent> menuComponents`. Then you would have noticed, that in your method `add(MenuComponent menuComponent)` you are allways adding the arrayList to the arrayList, because you made a simple typo.

It should be `menuComponents.add(menuComponent);` instead of `menuComponents.add(menuComponents);`. The same problem will occur in your remove method.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is here:

```
public void add(MenuComponent menuComponent) {
    menuComponents.add(menuComponents);//you add menuComponentS to the list!
}

public void remove(MenuComponent menuComponent) {
    menuComponents.remove(menuComponents);//you remove menuComponentS to the list!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem ist you add Arraylists in your Arraylist at this point

```
public void add(MenuComponent menuComponent) {
    menuComponents.add(menuComponents);
}
```

it has to be

```
public void add(MenuComponent menuComponent) {
    menuComponents.add(menuComponent);
}
```

you can simply avoid this by using typed Arraylist like this `ArrayList<MenuComponent> menuComponents = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 0):

First, do not use raw collections, like this:

```
ArrayList menuComponents = new ArrayList();
```

The proper way, is like this:

```
ArrayList<MenuComponent> menuComponents = new ArrayList<MenuComponent>();
```

Or better:

```
List<MenuComponent> menuComponents = new ArrayList<MenuComponent>();
```

This will allow you to eliminate the casts, like this:

```
return (MenuComponent) menuComponents.get(i);
```

and instead just do this:

```
return menuComponents.get(i);
```

This will allow Java to tell you if you are sticking the wrong things in the array, as in here:

```
menuComponents.add(menuComponents);
```

Java lets you get away with this because it has no idea what is *supposed* to be in `menuComponents`. When you say `new ArrayList<MenuComponent>()`, you are telling Java that the `ArrayList` can only have `MenuComponent` objects in it. Then, the above code will fail to compile, because Java knows you are doing the wrong thing and can tell you.